# Ajax affecting jQuery document load on ajax form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following jquery affecting cancelled bookings in a Drupal view, which works great.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".bookingstatus:contains('Cancelled')").css("color","red");
});
```

But, the drupal view uses a autosubmit checkbox to load bookings based on a chosen year, in an ajax display, when a user submits a change and ajax loads the new form, the jquery isn't used again. That makes sense though, as the (document).ready will only fire once when the user enters  the page, and not on every ajax request.

Updated:

This is what I am currently using, no more errors, and the colours show on the first page load like they did before, but the colours still aren't being changed after an ajax click.

```
(function ($) {
    $.post("/", $("#views-exposed-form-bookings-block").serialize(), function() {
        $(".bookingstatus:contains('Cancelled')").css("color","red");
        $(".bookingstatus:contains('Full Amount Paid')").css("color","green");
        $(".bookingstatus:contains('Deposit Paid')").css("color","blue");
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I don't understand why you decided to use `delegate` or `on` with a click event, when you clearly don't want to have to click to make the code run. Fortunately, the answer is easy: move the code that you need to execute when the ajax is ran to the ajax complete handler.

Comment: the *error* you are receiving shouldn't be happening in recent versions of jquery, which is why i'm hesitant to write an answer.

Comment: @KevinB You can go ahead and post an answer..Maybe it will be helpful to someone in the long run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Kevin B for your help, but the problem was with Drupal & views Ajax behaviours.

Sticking the jquery into a behaviour fixed it.

```
(function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
        $(".bookingstatus:contains('Cancelled')").css("color","red");
        $(".bookingstatus:contains('Full Amount Paid')").css("color","green");
        $(".bookingstatus:contains('Deposit Paid')").css("color","blue");
  }
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Ultimately that's the same concept, attaching it to the behavior has it run after the behavior does its thing. I'm glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

`.delegate` and `.on` only help with binding events; you aren't trying to bind any events. You should instead be using the ajax-submit success or complete callbacks.

```
$.post("act.php", $(theform).serialize(), function() {
    $(".bookingstatus:contains('Cancelled')").css("color","red");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I still can't get it to work. Drupal 7 ships with jQuery 1.4.4 as default. I am going to try updating the jQuery and see if that helps.

Comment: Same result with latest jQuery

Comment: Cant think of anything that would cause this to not work. What errors do you get? (make sure you check the console.)

Comment: Since upgrading jQuery, I get an error for the admin menu module (Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined ), but that's unrelated. Other than that, no errors in dev tools. The first value in post ("/",,), where should that be set to?

Comment: the absolute or relative path to the page you are posting to